# C# Generics: How to avoid code duplication when using struct constraints and nullables in lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Say I have a function such as:

```
    public TProperty Foo<TClass, TProperty>(TClass instance, Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        ...
    }
```

But then I realize it should only be used for value types, so I add a constraint

```
    public TProperty Foo<TClass, TProperty>(TClass instance, Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> expression)
        where TProperty : struct
    {
        ...
    }
```

But I then discover that this won't let me pass in expressions that take a nullable TProperty.  The only way I can see to handle this is to do the following:

```
    public TProperty Foo<TClass, TProperty>(TClass instance, Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty?>> expression)
        where TProperty : struct
    {
        ...
    }
```

But now I am forced to maintain *two* methods that do exactly the same thing, except that one deals with nullables, and one doesn't.

Further more I can't extract them into a common method, because even though a conversion exists from T to T?, there is apparently no conversion from

```
Expression<Func<T1, T2>>
```

to

```
Expression<Func<T1, T2?>>
```

If the body of these methods is complicated, I *really* don't want to have to maintain two separate versions of them, especially when in fact it is a whole family of functions.

Is there any way to avoid this code duplication and still have the compiler enforce that the expression must end in either a value type or a nullable?

(I am currently using C# 3.5, but am open to more recent versions if they provide a clean solution.)

Comment: I believe you can use reflection to convert from Expression<Func<T1,T2>> to Expression<Func<T1,T2?>> if you are determined enough. I just don't know the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing with the expression, you could make both overloads call a private overlaod that takes a (untyped) `LambdaExpression`.

Comment: Worked like a charm to just have the private common method take LambdaExpression, and the public methods call it explictly stating TClass and TProperty as necessary.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In cases like these it can be still OK to use method overloading provided the logic is refactored to a private method.

I think you can restrict it on `where TProperty : Nullable<TProperty>` though I have not checked this

Comment: The suggested where clause does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4, [`Func<P, Q>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549151.aspx) is actually [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) on `Q`. So this idea might work, but alas, `Nullable<T>` is not related to `T`. ([Here](http://ideone.com/YR4lS) is an example.), so `Func<P, Q>` has no chance to be used where `Func<P, Q?>` is expected.